# getting range of sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written this function, that outputs range of the following type of frame sequences.

```
frme.info.03.bmp
frme01_0040.bmp
frme01_0042.bmp
frme01_0043.bmp
frme02_0044.bmp
frme02_0045.bmp
frme02_0046.bmp
frme02_0047.bmp
frme03_0652.raw
frme03_0653.raw
frme03_0654.raw
frme03_0656.raw
frme03_0659.raw
frme1.45.dat
frme2.45.dat
frme3.45.dat
frme4.45.dat
```

and function I Wrote is:

```
def getRange(self, sequence, sep="_"):
    frameNumbers = []
    for item in sequence:
        frameNumbers.append(int(os.path.splitext(item)[0].split(sep)[-1]))
    return FrameRange(frameNumbers)
```

however this gives error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pe67'`

if I have a frame sequence of this type:

```
pe67.0140
pe67.0141
```

How should I handle all the cases above ?

Comment: Using a regular expression?

Comment: that would be fine too

Comment: check if extension is a number before your original code

Comment: What is your expected output? `frme1.45.dat` and `frme3.45.dat` could both give 45 or 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to divide the processing of the sting in logical steps. It doesn't have to be all in one line. Especially for debugging.

```
def getRange(sequence, sep="_"):
    frameNumbers = []
    for item in sequence:
        filename = os.path.splitext(item)[0]
        filename_parts = filename.split(sep)
        number_from_filename = filename_parts[-1]
        number = int(number_from_filename)
        frameNumbers.append(number)
    return frameNumbers
```

Your code produces:

```
('frme.info.03', '.bmp')
'frme.info.03'
'frme.info.03'  # (there is no _ to split at)
```

And it tries to convert that value to an int.

Comment: how do figure out what is the separator because in first case `_` is a separator but in later case `.` is separator.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a RegEx. Take every digit after a `.` or `_` which is followed by another `.`.

```
r = re.compile('(?:[._]+)([\d]+)')
for filename in filenames:
    search_result = re.search(r, filename)
    if not search_result is None:
        print(search_result.group(1))
    else:
        print('no match could be found')
```

or you just walk bruteforce backwards and take the first consecutive range of digits:

```
digits = [str(i) for i in range(0, 10)]
for filename in filenames:
    base_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    frame = ''
    for b in base_name[::-1]:
        if b in digits:
            frame = b + frame
        elif frame:
            print(frame)
            break
```

Both give you the same output:

> ```
> 03
> 0040
> 0042
> 0043
> 0044
> 0045
> 0046
> 0047
> 0652
> 0653
> 0654
> 0656
> 0659
> 45
> 45
> 45
> 45
> ```

Comment: you have ignored the case in which file sequence can be of the type `pe67.0140` -- `pe67.0141` leads to `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` error so I believe we  need to have a different regex for this case

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I adjusted the code accordingly. Is `pe67.0140` a filename without a filetype? Please add the info to your question.